# What's my favorite Pokemon? (besides Raichu, of course)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, acrostic

It's about time I did a puzzle based off Pokemon. The answer will be the answer to the question posed (what's my favorite Pokemon besides Raichu). Hints will be added as needed.

> eto(0,90,21) |  _ _ _ _ / _ _ kaeps tonnac ohw nosrep | forgo untyped | drizzle on the ball game |  u need a complete synonym | every running tree | as antimatter and matter, as like letters

Good luck! (| denotes separate puzzles, probably, and no, I didn't mess up the tags)

Minor Hint That Isn't Really a Hint:

> Each part will come out to a word or some set of letters.

Hint #1:

> rot13 on the only part that even looks cipher-like, and convert to hexadecimal

Hint #2 (for me neglecting to put any for so long)

> think word chains, and crossword clues

Hint #3 (Fairly Major)

> numbers to letters | solved already | anagram | crossword clue, one word | a bit of wordplay | check the tags | ???

Hint #4:

> for the first one, what letters do the numbers literally look like (and ignore zeros).

Hint #5:

> the end of one word leads into the beginning of the next, for example: concise / serve / verdant / anteater = conciserverdanteater

Hint #6:

> Forgo Untyped anagrams to "type of ground". u need a complete synonym- think of a different meaning of "complete synonym", maybe having something to do with the letter u?.

What you've got so far:

> **eto(0,90,21)**: solved (SAIS) 
>   **_ _ _ _ / _ _ kaeps tonnac ohw nosrep**: solved (ISMUTE) 
>  **forgo untyped**: partially solved, find something that continues the word chain 
>  **drizzle on the ball game**: solved (RAINOUT) 
>  **u need a complete synonym**: unsolved 
>  **every running tree**: solved (ERT) 
>  **as antimatter and matter, as like letters**: perhaps solve everything else first...

Comment: I PENG? I'm sure you are peng, darling.

Comment: An acrostic tag? ooookay

Comment: Is it trivial to say Pikachu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using previous answers (which did most of the work), the solution seems to be:

> **Samurott**

Explanation:

> These are definitions for a word chain, which eventually forms the pokemon's name when all of the *non-bridging* letters (that don't appear in the previous or next word) are singled out. So:
>
>  1. **SAis** [rot13 for rgb(0,90,12) which is #005A15 and looks like SAIS]
>  2. **isMUte**  ['is mute', the missing words in that sentence]
>  3. **teRrain**  [type of ground, which is an anagram of 'forgo untyped']
>  4. **rainOut** [clue from 'drizzle on the ball game']
>  5. **utTer**  [a synonym for 'complete' that starts with 'u']
>  6. **erT**  [the initials of 'every running tree']
>  7. *'as antimatter and matter, as like letters'*: This decribes the method of getting to the pokemon, by 'cancelling out' certain letters.

Comment: The part about antimatter and matter was a clue on how to get the answer, not on the final letters (the puzzle works without it), but this is the answer!

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu Thanks, I added that suggestion too a minute ago. This makes more sense; I'll re-edit.

Comment: Well done! Good to see the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Work in progress, maybe closer with more hints but still wrong:

> SAIS, E, OTG, WET, ERT, MAT = Mega Swampert

eto(0,91,21)

> "leet speak" rgb(0,90,12) = #005A15 = SAIS or SALS

_ _ _ _ / _ _ kaeps tonnac ohw nosrep

> solved: person who cannot speak is mute so 'etum si' = E

forgo untyped

> angram: of type ground

drizzle on the ball game

> one word crossword type: WET

u need a complete synonym

> wordplay:

every running tree

> check tags: ERT

as antimatter and matter, as like letters

> like letters in antimatter and matter, MAT

Answer (score 2):

Partial:
<s>Even with the new hint, I'm stuck. So I guess I'll put what I can.</s>

eto(0,90,21)

> rgb of some dark green. Personally, I took this to mean one of a couple of things: the pokemon is green, it's in either pokemon green / leaf green, or it's exclusive to either of those versions. Based on the new hint, it may be none of these.
>  based on hint 4: sals
>  Was wrong, is "sais"

forgo untyped

> I think this is an anagram for "of type ground", rather, a ground type mon.
>  New: terrain

drizzle on the ball game

> rain / rainout / drizzle? Maybe a move or ability of the mon?
>  Confirmed: rainout

u need a complete synonym

> synonym for complete with a u: utter

This all gives us:

> saismuterrainouttert

as antimatter and matter, as like letters

> If opposites, then perhaps "numbers"
>  but, they don't destroy each other. Also, it could just be wordplay or who knows...
>  So now, what do we do with it?

I mean, I'm kinda looking at:

> Sandshrew or Sandslash, but I don't think that's right.

Comment: One of your guesses for one of the clues is actually correct!

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

> *"_ _ _ _ / _ _ kaeps tonnac ohw nosrep"* written backwards is *"person who cannot speak _ _ / _ _ _ _"* I believe each _ represents a letter, so this sentence would be completed with *is mute*. This backwards is then *etumsi* (if that has any relevance).

Comment: My guess is it's just 'e' at the 'start' of mute that contributes to the acrostic

Answer (score 1):

Partial:
eto(0,90,21)

> if you use rot 13 you get rgb(0,90,21) which is a darkish green colour (will add image later)

Comment: I wonder if this green has a name? It would contribute towards the acrostic quality of the puzzle. Unless it's just 'green'